# SwiftUI Custom Alert action block does not execute

Tags: swiftui, uikit, uialertcontroller

I want to achieve an alert that has a text field embedded in it WITHOUT the help of iOS 16. It went smoothly until I wanted to update a variable when I press one of the buttons.

Currently, I have the custom alert code, which is straight up copied from a YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FqRNf2WbJE) that works perfectly:

```
extension View {
    func alertTF(title: String, message: String, hintText: String, primaryTitle: String, secondaryTitle: String, primaryAction: @escaping (String) -> (), secondaryAction: @escaping () -> () ) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField { field in
            field.placeholder = hintText
        }
        
        alert.addAction(.init(title: secondaryTitle, style: .cancel, handler: { _ in
            secondaryAction()
        }))
        
        alert.addAction(.init(title: primaryTitle, style: .default, handler: { _ in
            if let text = alert.textFields?[0].text {
                primaryAction(text)
            } else {
                primaryAction("")
            }
        }))
        
        rootController().present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func rootController() -> UIViewController {
        guard let screen = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else {
            return .init()
        }
        
        guard let root = screen.windows.first?.rootViewController else {
            return .init()
        }
        
        return root
    }
}
```

and here's the SwiftUI code that calls it:

```
@State private var submittedExportRequest = false

...

VStack {
     ARViewWrapper(submittedExportRequest: $submittedExportRequest, exportedURL: $exportedURL, submittedName: submittedName)
         .ignoresSafeArea()
                
     Button("Export") {
        alertTF(title: "Save as", message: "Please enter your file name", hintText: "my_file", primaryTitle: "Save", secondaryTitle: "cancel") { text in
        print(text)
        submittedName = text
        
        // Does not update my binding value.
        submittedExportRequest.toggle()

        } secondaryAction: {
            print("cancelled")
        }
    }
}
```

and a `UIViewRepresentable` View that is supposed to be called when one of the button is pressed:

```
@Binding var submittedExportRequest: Bool
@Binding var exportedURL: URL?
var submittedName: String

...

func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
        
        // This does not get executed 
        if submittedExportRequest {
            ...
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the alert does not update my binding that was supposed to be passed in and refresh my `UIViewRepresentable`. Would be grateful if anyone could offer advice on how to approach this. Thanks!

Comment: why you are toggle value of button 2 times that's why it is not going to call `if submittedExportRequest` you need to remove `submittedExportRequest.toggle()` before `alertTF(title: "Save as"` in `VStack`. add `submittedExportRequest.toggle()`  only on tap on `Save` button which is already added then check. I don't know what code has your `func makeUIView(context: Context)` method so according to value you can update it.

Comment: Nice catch. I accidentally uncommented my code in the previous line, and I had two while pasting it into StackOverflow. It still doesn't work with one toggle though.

Comment: Keep in mind that ARViewWrapper is a View and would not affect the order because state changes should still be able to occur regardless of its placement

Comment: Although I am reading the View before changing it, shouldn't it still update when `submittedExportRequest` updates its boolean? I thought UpdateUIView means that it will keep obtaining new changes and would take in the binding.

Comment: Sorry my bad, actually my mistake in code but i'm getting update value with `submittedExportRequest.toggle()` and able to execute that code `if submittedExportRequest {`

Comment: Can you add your solution as an answer, so I know what to change? Thanks

Comment: I've just check with this code `func updateUIView(_ uiView: MyUIView, context: Context) {
        if submittedExportRequest {
            print("True")
        } else {
            print("False")
        }
    }` with one `submittedExportRequest.toggle()` and it's get printed with value `True` when click on `Save` button

Comment: So you copied my code and made no adjustments and it works?

Comment: i have just remove first time `submittedExportRequest.toggle()` and able to call `func updateUIView(` that function and get updated value